# What version of Ubuntu supports installing alongside Windows 8?

Tags: 12.04, installation, 13.04, dual-boot, windows-8

I have a laptop with Windows 8 pre-installed. I want to install Ubuntu alongside, but the last time I tried, there was `12.04` and it did not recognize Windows 8, and therefore did not let me install alongside it. Is this issue fixed for `12.04`? If not, should I go with `13.04`? In that case, does 13.04 have any disadvantages over 12.04?

[The laptop](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/pcs/NP915S3G-K01US-features/) seems to support `13.04` better as I've read on the net. [This poster here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345917/samsung-ativ-book-9-lite-ubuntu-12-04-lts-13-04-howto/) says that wifi driver works on `13.04`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried Ubuntu 13.04 dual boot with Windows 8 as a live USB system. Although it worked once out of ten times, it worked. But, the wifi driver was "disabled by a hardware switch" (WIERD).

I recently install **Kubuntu 12,04** and it was perfect. I don't know whether you like the KDE version of Ubuntu, but everything worked and still works (wifi, screensaver, software center, sudo (terminal), applications in general. I hope it helps.

Regards,

The Drummer from Kubuntu

Comment: What do you mean it did not work? It failed to show the "install alongside" option? I mean, it's not end of the world: I could always try to create each partition manually, but I'd really prefer not to, because I'd tried it in the past, and not succeeded. I've never used Kubuntu, and I'm comfortable with Ubuntu. I must admit, I don't really know how different they are from each other, though.

Comment: With my laptop with Windows 8 installed, I booted Ubuntu both 12.04 and 13.04. Only Kubuntu 12.04 worked (I have not tried the 13.04 version though). The only way to create the partitions manually is to respect the 4GB limitation and to be careful of which partition you are making/resizing/deleting. I am being out of context: **how do you solve your problem so far?**

Comment: I went with 13.04. Everything went wrong because of the BIOS. [Please see the post here.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/349206/ubuntu-13-04-install-gone-wrong-no-gui-in-ubuntu-and-cannot-boot-into-windows-8/)

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is described well [here](http://gingerbreaddesign.co.uk/todd/2012/11/09/ubuntu-windows-8-dual-boot-on-asus-ux31a/)
Another place is  [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)
The steps appear to be

1. **Create a Windows Recovery DVD(s) and back up any important
   data**
2. Use the Windows diskmanager to shrink the windows partition
3. Create a Bootable Ubuntu LiveUSB
4. Disable Secure Boot and Disable Fast Start up
5. Install Ubuntu from USB ...Make sure you select the "install
   alongside" option
6. Use [Ubutu Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool if Windows does
   not boot

As for choosing 13.04 over 12.04.  Well 12.04 is Long Term Supported, but is  a year older.  Each generation is more more compatible with newer hardware. Choice is yours.

Comment: I know those steps, and it is not what I am asking for. `12.04` did not have an install alongside option when Windows 8 just came out. This was a known issue. I am asking with which version I am least likely to have that issue again. If my phrasing in the original question was not clear enough, I do apologize.